# How to work around the fact that Linq to SQL is using separate SQL DELETE statements for each item in DeleteAllOnSubmit

Tags: sql, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

When using a DeleteAllOnSubmit statement like the following (I'm omitting DataContext because I'm using LinqPad here)

```
var deleteUs = Foo.Take(9658);
Foo.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deleteUs);
SubmitChanges();
```

the resulting SQL Code looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (9658) [t0].[id] FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int SET @p0 = 1
-- EndRegion
DELETE FROM [Foo] WHERE [id] = @p0
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int SET @p0 = 2
-- EndRegion
DELETE FROM [Foo] WHERE [id] = @p0
GO
... and so on
```

Line 2 in the c# code can't know that line 1 translates to a SELECT TOP statement and that it would be much faster to use a DELETE TOP statement.

**Question**: how do I work around this without resorting to SQL? Is there a way to make Linq statements translate to DELETE TOP or something similar?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid SQL here? Seems like the perfect solution.

Comment: Immaterial, but your first line could be simply `Foo.Take(9658)`

Comment: @Andrew Barber: for one thing, it's a matter of style not to mix SQL string into the code, secondly you'd have to use a second data access method, thirdly I really want to know whether this has been covered by the Microsoft team because they claim that the framework produced quite optimized SQL code (which I believe it usually does.

Comment: @Marc: thanks, true, I am aware of that (originally I had a more complex statement from which I removed characters). I'll correct that.

Comment: @Olaf There's no reason your C# code would need to have SQL in it; Stored Procs can be part of L2S DataContexts. I understand the academic part, though.

Comment: @Andrew: True, part of it is academic and learning stuff. As for the SPs - I don't mind not having them at all (even though in this case they don't contain business logic, but still...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom query generator with an extension method should allow you to perform batch deletes:

http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx

I am not sure however if it supports `Take` operator.

Comment: Very nice link. Haven't found that when googling.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a stored proc with a table variable as the input variable? You can call stored procs from LINQ.

I don't see any reason not to use SQl for the job it was intended to do if the ORM creates badly performing SQL.

Comment: Andrew Barber already suggested using a SP in a comment. It's definitely a way, but my question was at least partly academic - I just want to know if there is another way (because I think this is quite a common task) or understand why there is none.